# Print java static variable from another class

Tags: java

I would like to print the static variable of another class but I cant for some reason. Here is the error when compiling:

```
System.out.println(Creature.MAX_Y);
                               ^
  symbol:   variable MAX_Y
  location: class Creature
1 error
```

Here is the code for the Creature class:

```
package naturalselection.creature;

import naturalselection.food.Food;
import naturalselection.vector.Vector;
import naturalselection.creature.Target;
import java.util.*;
public class Creature{
  public static short MAX_X = 150;
  public static short MAX_Y = 150;
}
```

and the main class:

```
import naturalselection.creature.Creature;
import naturalselection.food.Food;

class Main{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Creature c1 = new Creature(1, 1);
    System.out.println(Creature.MAX_Y);
  }
}
```

Here is the directory structure (part of it):

```
main.java
naturalselection -
+-- creature
    +-- Creature.java
```

Comment: Maybe a namespace/package problem. Please [edit] your question to include the complete file contents of your `.java` files. Also show how you compile your files.

Comment: @Progman I added the packages, the .java file for the Creature.java file is 200 lines long... but I've included the .java file for main

Comment: Recompile the `naturalselection.creature.Creature` class. Also check if you have a different `Creature` class (or even a `Creature.class` file somewhere) somewhere which is used instead. You might want to delete all `.class` files and recompile everything.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare static variable in that class from where you are trying to get variable.
public static String variableName = "Value";

Comment: No. This is blatantly wrong. You can refer to constants in other classes, and it is a very common design pattern.